# Error when using index inside a .Select in a LINQ QUery:

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following codes:

```
        //var testQuestionHeaders = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
        //        .Where(m => m.Problem != null &&
        //        m.Problem.SubTopic != null &&
        //        m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic != null &&
        //        m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 1)
        //        .Select(m => new TestQuestionHeader
        //        {
        //            Id = 1,
        //            QId = m.QuestionId,
        //            A = false,
        //            C = 0,
        //            F = 0
        //        })
        //        .ToList();

        var testQuestionHeaders = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(m => m.Problem != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 1)
            .Select((m, index) => new TestQuestionHeader
            {
                Id = index + 1,
                QId = m.QuestionId,
                A = false,
                C = 0,
                F = 0
            })
            .ToList();
```

The first code (now commented out) works but when I add in the use of index I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Http.TestQuestionHeader] Select[Question,TestQuestionHeader](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Core.Question], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Models.Core.Question,System.Int32,Models.Http.TestQuestionHeader]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Services.QuestionService.GetTestQuestionHeadersBySubject(Int32 subjectId) in S146\Services\QuestionService.cs:line 100
       at Web.Controllers.TestController.CreateTestData() in S146\WebRole1\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 39
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

Can someone give me some advice on this. It's very repeatable and it's important for me to have some way of setting the Id to a different value in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the exception is rather clear :

You can't use this overload of `Select` (the one with an `Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector` parameter) in a linq to entities query (on an `IQueryable<T>` which is used for a linq to entities query).

So if you need it, you've got to enumerate first

```
.ToList()
.Select((m, index) =>...
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick answer. After I make it into a list do I need to do that again later at the end also?

Comment: well, if you don't, you'll get an `IEnumerable<TestQuestionHeader>`.So it depdends on your needs. If you need a `List<TestQuestionHeader>`... Yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

1) Calling .ToList() before the select makes you do a huge select (if your table has multiple filelds) for nothing

2) Instead of calling .ToList() or .ToArray(), which makes you loose the lazy enumeration advantage, you could use:

```
var lazyEnumerated = Enumerable.Select(testQuestionHeaders , (m, index) =>
                {
                    m.Id += index;
                    return m;
                });
```

where `testQuestionHeaders` is the first select you commented out.

Comment: then, call objs.AsEnumerable() or cast it to IEnumerable :)
The point is: It must not call Queryable.Select()